# load sub-component programmatically in Angular

Tags: angular

I would like to decide which sub-component to use programmatically.  It is basically the same question asked here [Load component programmatically in angular 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49649104/load-component-programmatically-in-angular-1-6), but using Angular 6.

So, I would like to have something like this:

**parent.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() loadedComponentName = "my-component";

  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<{{loadedComponentName}}></{{loadedComponentName}}>
```

Comment: check this https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: Thank you. I think I can work with that